# Primefaces 2.2.1 to 3.0.1 Upgrade Issue with Mapping/Locating Spring Managed Beans

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

**Background:**

I'm using the below two classes (Search.java and SearchBean.java) in a Primefaces web application (version 2.2.1). All of my classes in the `com.actions` package are request scoped beans that handle the business logic in my application (actionListeners, Listeners, etc).  The classes in the `com.beans` package are all session scoped beans that maintain state about the application. Each request scoped has an instance of a session scoped bean injected using CDI and each are managed by Spring.

**Issue:**

When I upgraded to 3.0.1 the classes are not getting registered by Primefaces and I get an error message like *Property 'test' not found on type com.actions.Search*.  This happens on every single method that's mapped from a Primefaces component to either the request or session beans below. Any ideas on what are the appropriate changes?

**Exception:**

```
javax.el.ELException: /WEB-INF/facelet/components/test.xhtml: Property 'process' not found on type com.actions.Search
com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.AttributeInstruction.write(AttributeInstruction.java:94)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:853)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1652)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1655)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1655)
    javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1655)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:399)
    com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:313)
    org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:115)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    com.dc.api.service.impl.CacheControlFilter.doFilter(CacheControlFilter.java:31)
    com.dc.api.service.impl.HttpsCookieFilter.doFilter(HttpsCookieFilter.java:46)
```

Class that handles business logic and holds an instance of a session scoped bean

```
package com.actions;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import com.beans.SearchBean;

@Named
@Scope("request")
public class Search{
    @Inject
    private SearchBean searchBean;

    public void process() { 
        //business logic here
        searchBean.get...
    }
}
```

Bean that maintains data in session state

```
package com.beans;

import javax.inject.Named;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

@Named
@Scope("session")
public class SearchBean {
    private String text="test";
    //getters and setters
}
```

The below alternate approach also is not working (just using one bean):

```
package com.actions;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("session")
public class Search {

    public void sessionIdleListener() { 
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please confirm you are adhering to proper getter/setter for java bean properties have a look @ [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577545/javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-property-answer-not-found-on-type-com-pool)

Comment: @gbagga - yeah it does.  All I changed was the version of Primefaces.

Comment: can you check differences in tag currently being used by you from primefaces may be a property of tag was present in version 2 but not in version 3

Comment: the problem was the namespace for the Primefaces tags was changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was resolved by providing the new Primefaces 3.0.1 namespace of xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" as it had changed from the former version of xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"