# Outcommented Facelets code still invokes EL expressions like #{bean.action()} and causes javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException on #{bean.action}

Tags: jsf, comments, el, facelets, propertynotfoundexception

I've the following code snippet in my Facelet:

```
<h:commandLink id="cmdbtn">
    <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form"
            listener="#{screenShotBean.takeScreenshot}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

It works fine, but when I outcomment it like this,

```
<!--        <h:commandLink id="cmdbtn"> -->
<!--            <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" -->
<!--                    listener="#{screenShotBean.takeScreenshot}" /> -->
<!--        </h:commandLink> -->
```

then it throws the following exception:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'takeScreenshot' not found on type monstage.test.com.ScreenShotBean
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:237)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:214)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:325)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.toString(ELText.java:217)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.toString(ELText.java:157)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CommentInstruction.write(CommentInstruction.java:77)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UIInstructions.encodeBegin(UIInstructions.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.UILeaf.encodeAll(UILeaf.java:183)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:424)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
```

When I change the method expression with parentheses as below,

```
<!--        <h:commandLink id="cmdbtn"> -->
<!--            <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" -->
<!--                    listener="#{screenShotBean.takeScreenshot()}" /> -->
<!--        </h:commandLink> -->
```

Then doesn't throw the exception, but it's still invoked.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: by the way, i tried to resolve this problem by changing all elements finishing by "/> " to the complete notation form but it didn't work

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Look closer at the stack trace. Here's the relevant part:

```
...
org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextVariable.toString(ELText.java:217)
com.sun.faces.facelets.el.ELText$ELTextComposite.toString(ELText.java:157)
com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.CommentInstruction.write(CommentInstruction.java:77)
...
```

It's thus evaluating EL in a comment block (recognizable by `CommentInstruction`). A comment block is considered as template text. Facelets evaluates by default also EL `#{}` in template text. It's like as if you're writing `<p>#{screenShotBean.takeScreenshot}</p>` without any JSF tag.

You've several options:

1. Remove the comment block altogether.
2. Escape EL expressions in the comment by prefixing it with `\` as in

   ```
   \#{screenShotBean.takeScreenshot}
   ```

   so that they won't be evaluated.
3. Wrap the entire comment block in [`<ui:remove>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/remove.html) so that it doesn't appear in the component tree (nor in the generated HTML output).
4. Disable parsing of **all** comments by Facelets by adding the following context parameter to `web.xml`:

   ```
   <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
   </context-param>
   ```

   Note that no one comment will end up in generated HTML output this way.

Comment: I used your suggested option 4 and fixed the problem of propertyNotFoundException. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the [options BalusC already provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14692966/880619) you could also add the attribute `rendered="false"` to your `commandLink`.

If you have several components you want to be able to toggle quickly, you might want to consider creating a debug property in a bean or use the project stage:

```
rendered="#{facesContext.application.projectStage == 'Development'}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the context parameter that skips comments in your web.xml.

This is the parâmeter:

```
javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS
```