# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'xxx' does not have a readable property 'yyy'

Tags: jsf, el, managed-bean, propertynotfoundexception

I've the below session scoped CDI managed bean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class RegisterController implements Serializable {   
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private MitgliedAbc mitgliedAbc;

    public MitgliedAbc getMitgliedABC() {
        return mitgliedAbc;
    }

    public void setMitgliedAbc (MitgliedAbc mitgliedAbc) {
        this.mitgliedAbc = mitgliedAbc;
    }

}
```

And the following input in a JSF form:

```
<h:inputText value="#{registerController.mitgliedAbc.mgEmail}" />
```

When deploying to GlassFish 4.1 and opening the page in browser, the following exception is thrown:

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /register.xhtml @27,66
>   value="#{registerController.mitgliedAbc.mgEmail}": The class
>   'com.example.RegisterController' does not
>   have a readable property 'mitgliedAbc'.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: You should add the code of the class `RegisterController` to the question.

Comment: Hi BalusC,thanks a lot! I knew it that it must be a typo, but I was blind and couldn't find it.couldn't  wsa a typo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'foo' not found on type com.example.Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577545/javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-property-foo-not-found-on-type-com-example)

Answer (score 13):

> *javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'xxx' does not have a readable property 'yyy'*

This basically means that the class `xxx` does not have a (valid) getter method for property `yyy`.

In other words, the following EL expression which should output the value,

```
#{xxx.yyy}
```

was unable to find a `public Yyy getYyy()` method on class `xxx`.

In your particular case, with the following EL expression,

```
#{registerController.mitgliedAbc}
```

it was unable to find a `public MitgliedAbc getMitgliedAbc()` property.

And indeed, that method doesn't exist. It's named `getMitgliedABC()` instead of `getMitgliedAbc()`.

Fix the method name accordingly to exactly match `getYyy()` and make absolutely sure it's `public` and non-`static`.

```
public MitgliedAbc getMitgliedAbc() {
    return mitgliedAbc;
}
```

#### See also:

- [javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'foo' not found on type com.example.Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577545/javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-property-foo-not-found-on-type-com-example)
- [Identifying and solving javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128395/identifying-and-solving-javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-target-unreachable)

Comment: Hi BalusC,thanks a lot! I knew it that it must be a typo, but I was blind and couldn't find it.  Thanks, Franz

Comment: this tip works for me "it's public and non-static". I was trying to access member of static inner class.

Comment: Thanks! I've forgot to add getter setter on my code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I got the solution

This is my Emp Model

```
public class Emp {
    private String Eid;
    private String Ename;
    private String Mobile;
    private String Email;

    public String getEid() {
        return Eid;
    }

    public void setEid(String Eid) {
        this.Eid = Eid;
    }

    public String getEname() {
        return Ename;
    }

    public void setEname(String Ename) {
        this.Ename = Ename;
    }

.........etc
```

And my Controller method

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/welcome", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView CtrlMethod(@ModelAttribute("employee1") Emp employee1) {
         ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("hellopage");
         return model;    
    }
```

In My (hellopage.jsp) JSP Page I mentioned like bellow and it works for me.

```
 ${employee1.getEid()}
 ${employee1.getEname()}
 ${employee1.getMobile()}
 ${employee1.getEmail()}
```