# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class ' does not have a readable property 'preference'

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

I have been through almost all the related questions on SO but couldn't find the answer because I don't have the issues that were the cause of errors for other still I've same error result.

I have implemented a primefaces **selectBooleanButton** element and included the bean code as per that only. The error means that the system is unable to read the property of the managedBean but I have proper getter/setter methods as it should be for boolean property. Below is the code for reference:

**View**

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
  <ui:composition template="/templates/common/public.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">Search</ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
      <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive">
        <div class="ui-grid-row">
          <div class="ui-grid-col-10" id="mainCol">
            <h:form id="search">
              <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
              <h:outputText value="Choose: " />
              <p:selectBooleanButton id="preference" value="#{searchForm.preference}" onLabel="Yes" offLabel="No" style="width:60px" />
            </h:form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ui:define>
  </ui:composition>
</html>
```

**Bean:**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class SearchForm {

  private boolean preference;

  public boolean isPreference() {
      return preference;
  }

  public void setPreference(boolean preference) {
      this.preference = preference;
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
[glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] [tid: _ThreadID=26 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1488954548903] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Error Rendering View[/search/searchForm.xhtml]
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /search/searchForm.xhtml @49,156 value="#{searchForm.preference}": The class 'com.pc.SearchForm' does not have a readable property 'preference'.
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'xxx' does not have a readable property 'yyy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27769814/javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-the-class-xxx-does-not-have-a-readable-pro)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It been a  long time for this question but posting this answer just to mention the cause and close the issue.

It was **glassfish not picking up the changes and restarting it resolved the issue**.
So, if you are sure about your changes and still getting an error, I guess its ok to doubt the server too :)

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but this may help somebody. I had a similar problem with `Boolean`. Changing the getter method from `isXxx` to `getXxx` solved it. For instance:

```
public boolean getPreference() {
    return preference;
}
```