# Jersey Links (hateoas) in combination with QueryParameters

Tags: java, jersey, query-string

I want te create an endpoint something like: http://localhost:8080/privacy-preferences?category=6&type=21 When i run this everything works fine and i do get my Hateoas links. So, something like:

```
 preferences": [
        {
        "links": [
        {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "privacy-preferences"
        },
        {
        "rel": "update",
        "href": "privacy-preferences/3/7",
        "method": "put"
        },
        {
        "rel": "delete",
        "href": "privacy-preferences",
        "method": "delete"
        }
        ],
        "code": 7,
        "enabled": true,
        "name": "some name",
        "category": 3
        }
        ]
```

When i leave one of the query parameters i get an error.
The url looks like:
http://localhost:8080/privacy-preferences?category=3

```
    The error i get:
    javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'type' not found on type nl.company.api.privacy.dto.PreferencesDto
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:269)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:221)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:356)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:95)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:63)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.linking.ELLinkBuilder.getParameterValues(ELLinkBuilder.java:153)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.linking.ELLinkBuilder.buildURI(ELLinkBuilder.java:111)
```

Does anybody know how to handle hateoas links in combination with query parameters ?

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: You have your answer in the error: `PropertyNotFoundException` ... Take a look at this:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577545/javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-property-foo-not-found-on-type-com-example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'foo' not found on type com.example.Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577545/javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-property-foo-not-found-on-type-com-example)