# Is it more safe to use getter instead of field name in EL?

Tags: jsp, el

I'm using EL in my JSP. For example

Case 1:

`<h5>${fgst.userFlag}</h5>`

Case 2:

`<h5>${fgst.getUserFlag()}</h5>`

I want to know, Do case 2 is more secure and safe way to access data from model then case 1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference in security.

Note that `${fgst.userFlag}` does not access the field at all. Under the covers, it converts the property name `userFlag` to a getter method `getUserFlag()` and finally invokes it on the instance represented by `${fgst}`. In other words, it does exactly the same as `${fgst.getUserFlag()}`.

You can confirm for yourself by renaming the field name while keeping the getter method name unchanged. You'll notice that both approaches continue to work and that they both actually invoke the getter method, which can also be observed by putting a debug breakpoint on the getter method.

#### See also:

- [javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'foo' not found on type com.example.Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577545/javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-property-foo-not-found-on-type-com-example)