# org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet' does not have the property 'size'

Tags: jsp, el, propertynotfoundexception

On the JSP page, I am doing like this `${records.size}`
where records is of `Set` type. Then I am getting this error.
I check the documentation and `size()` method is available in `org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet`.
So what could be possible reason for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax `${records.size}` basically tells EL to print the `size` **property** (not method!) of the bean as identified by `${records}`. When EL needs to obtain a property, then it will look up the getter method in the class behind the bean. So when the property name is `size` then the expected getter method is `getSize()`. If this method is absent, then you will face exactly the exception you're currently facing. See also [javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'foo' not found on type com.example.Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8577545/javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-property-foo-not-found-on-type-com-example).

And indeed, the `org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet` **does not** have the `getSize()` method. I.e. it does indeed not have the `size` property at all. So the exception is completely right.

Basically you want to invoke the `size()` method instead, not the getter method behind the `size` property. Fix your EL expression accordingly:

```
${records.size()}
```

Comment: You are right regarding this question. Actually records is my embedded collection and to get its size on JSP using 'fn: length' I need to initialize each record. I read somewhere using @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA) you can use size() ,isEmpty() methods directly without initializing it. And it works when I call the size() method from the controller. But when I try to access size() method on JSP page it again throws an error- failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: xxx, could not initialize proxy - no Session.